# How to connect to a mysql database in C# and mimic the SELECT, UPDATE and INSERT functions

Tags: c#, php, mysql, database

How can I connect to a MySQL database in C#, and use it to `UPDATE` values in the database, `INSERT` values in the database and `SELECT` values from the database.

Also, is it possible to get the value of the row, and mimic this PHP in C#?

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM foo WHERE foo = 'foo');
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
$foo1 = $row['foo1'];
//and so on
}
```

Comment: I guess what you're looking for is MySql's Connector/NET... Google that... there's a tonne of "getting started" tutorials out there. Comeback to SO with any SPECIFIC questions. Cheers. Keith.

Comment: Import the Connector/Net (http://www.mysql.de/downloads/connector/net/) into your project and do it like so: http://bitdaddys.com/MySQL-ConnectorNet.html (or like in the countless other tutorials you can find via google...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to download the [MySql Connector/.NET](http://bitdaddys.com/MySQL-ConnectorNet.html).

[How to connect to MySQL 5.0 using c# and mysql connector/net!](http://bitdaddys.com/MySQL-ConnectorNet.html) lists some sample code which is quite similar to what you have:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
  string MyConString = "SERVER=localhost;" +
                       "DATABASE=mydatabase;" +
                       "UID=testuser;" +
                       "PASSWORD=testpassword;";
  MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(MyConString);
  MySqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
  MySqlDataReader Reader;
  command.CommandText = "select * from mycustomers";
  connection.Open();
  Reader = command.ExecuteReader();
  while (Reader.Read())
  {
    string thisrow = "";
    for (int i= 0;i<Reader.FieldCount;i++)
      thisrow+=Reader.GetValue(i).ToString() + ",";
    listBox1.Items.Add(thisrow);
  }
  connection.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have to learn about [ADO.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/27y4ybxw%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) provider classes - They are responsible to establish a database session, execute commands (queries) and retrieve the results) and after that you have to download the [MySql Connector](http://www.mysql.com/products/connector/) API (Data Provider API) and learn the Provider class of mysql connector.

[Connector/NET Examples](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/connector-net-examples.html)

Answer (score 0):

1- add References to my project : MySql.Data.MySqlClient

2- install the MySQL for Visual Studio download link : 
https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/visualstudio/

note: to create database Mysql free go to the link:

### https://www.freesqldatabase.com/

the code :

```
string stconnetionString = "Server=Server name; Port=port number; 
         Database= DB name; Uid=User namw; Pwd=password;";

MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(stconnetionString);

try
{
    conn.Open();
    MySqlCommand mycmd = conn.CreateCommand();
    mycmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    mycmd.CommandText = "insert into Student(columes name) values(.....)";
    mycmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
    MessageBox.Show("Saved", "Window Application ", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    clear();
}
catch (Exception)
{

    throw;
}
```